# Is there an easy way to move startup entries from HKLM to HKCU using Autoruns64.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

There are a few programs with Registry startup entries I don't want to start on all user accounts within:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Using AutoRuns64, or anything else, is it possible to move these Registry entries to here so they only start within my main user account:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

- I cannot find a way to do this using AutoRuns64; there is a way to copy an entry, but no apparent way to paste it back into another registry hive location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping for an easy way to do this, but what I did in the end wasn't so difficult, as even if there is an option on installation to choose whether to run for all users or not, I don't get to choose, as I use `winget` to install everything by command line.

1. Running AutoRuns64 as Admin, right-click the blue line for the key below, which is the section where these startup entries were, and select *Jump to Entry*:

   ```reg
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   ```

   1. This opens the Registry Editor where the key can be exported; afterwards, delete the entries within that key
2. Copy the exported `.reg` file and edit the copy *(the original can be used to restore the entries)*:

   ```reg
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
   "WordWeb"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordWeb\\wweb32.exe\" -startup"
   "Dropbox"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dropbox\\Client\\Dropbox.exe\" /systemstartup"
   "Adobe Creative Cloud"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Creative Cloud\\ACC\\Creative Cloud.exe\" --showwindow=false --onOSstartup=true"
   "Adobe CCXProcess"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe Creative Cloud Experience\\CCXProcess.exe"
   ```

   1. Change the key at the top to the following, save the file, and import the key by double-clicking the file:

      ```reg
      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
      ```
3. Reboot

---

Now only the current user account has these startup programs, and they won't start up within any other account.

Comment: True, but this answer no longer corresponds to the title of the question. From this perspective, the other answer is correct: it is not possible via Autoruns64.exe. (As you found out, it is possible only via generic export/deletion/editing/import.)

Comment: Note that doing this will break the uninstall/deployment information, so the entries won't be cleaned up if you choose later to remove the app.

Comment: @throx Not a problem as they don't do anything if the executable isn't present and my installations are pretty ephemeral anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Autoruns (I have it here and I use it) just lists entries in startup locations and manages / filters what you can list.

> Is there an easy way to move startup entries from HKML to HKCU using
> Autoruns64.exe?

No.

> which I don't want starting in all user accounts.

That is a function of the App you installed and certainly not Autoruns.

An App can install for one user (common), or for all users (not so common and almost always optional).

You may be able to uninstall the App, restart and choose how it will be installed. This is not always possible, so you may have to live with the way the App was designed.

You can also may point Autoruns to App Properties and possibly make changes there (depending on the App) but that is a Windows function, not an Autoruns function.

Comment: Thanks, but it is actually possible as I found out.

Comment: I looked at Autoruns here and for Apps for which you cannot set the All Users flag, Autoruns does not allow change. What you found (opening the properties) would be for limited situations. At that is the Windows properties in any event, not really Autoruns.